# Proof about invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let A and B be $n \times n$ matrices such that $AB=I_n$
>
> b). Prove $A=B^{-1}$(and hence $B=A^{-1}$)
>
> c). State and prove analogous results for linear mappings defined on finite-dimensional vector spaces.

[image]

I just proved from definition. Is it ok?

> Definition: Let V and W be vector spaces, and let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be linear. A function $U:W \rightarrow V$ is an inverse of T if $TU=I_W$ and $UT=I_V$.If T has an inverse, then T is invertible.

Comment: I think the point is to show that BA=I as well

Comment: To multiply with the inverse of a matrix, first you should prove that it has an inverse.

Comment: This is unanswerable before you tell us what results you know about invertible matrices.

Comment: According to the above definition, the *inverse* of a $m\times n$ matrix $A$ must be a $n\times m$ matrix $C$ such that $AC = I_m$ and $CA = I_n$. Now, the question is, how do you know that if $m=n$ and if there exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB = I_n$, also $BA = I_n$ (and hence $A$ and $B$ are inverses of each other)?

Comment: @Azif00 so am I supposed to prove A and B are invertible respectively?

Comment: Yes, I add an answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $E$ be a square matrix. Then, the following are equivalent:

$\rm (a)$ $E$ is invertible.

$\rm (b)$ The only solution for $E\vec{x} = \vec0$ is $\vec{x} = \vec0$.

$\rm (c)$ For any vector $\vec y$, there exists a vector $\vec x$ such that $\vec{y} = E\vec{x}$.

Now, use $\rm (b)$ to show that $B$ is invertible, and use $\rm (c)$ to show that $A$ is invertible.